# echoing array from function in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array from a function.

The function:

```
$results = [];
function getDirEnties($directory, &$results) {
    $entries = scandir($directory);
    foreach ($entries as $item) {
        if (!in_array($item, ['.', '..']) && substr($item, 0, 1) !== '.') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;
            if (is_dir($path)) {
                getDirEnties($path, $results);
            } else {
                $pathInfo = pathinfo($path);
                $name = $pathInfo['filename'];
                $type = 'unknown';
                if (!empty($pathInfo['extension'])) {
                    $name .= "." . $pathInfo['extension'];
                    switch (strtolower($pathInfo['extension'])) {
                        case "gif":
                        case "jpg":
                        case "png":
                        case "jpeg":
                        case "bmp":
                        //etc..
                        $type = 'image';
                        break;
                        case "mp4":
                        $type = 'media';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            $data = [
                'name' => $name,
                'path' => $pathInfo['dirname'],
                'type' => $type,
                'time' => filemtime($path)
                ];
            $results[] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

to populate the function I have the following:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends 
                    WHERE (friend1 = :username AND friend2 <> :username) 
                    UNION
                    SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends
                    WHERE (friend2 = :username AND friend1 <> :username)');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$friend_rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($friend_rows as $rows) {
    $friend = strtolower($rows['username']);
    $directoryToScan = '/path/to/'.$friend;
    $tree = getDirEnties($directoryToScan, $results);
}
```

I am then trying to echo it out as follows:

```
function cmp($a, $b)  {
    $ad = new DateTime($a['time']);
    $bd = new DateTime($b['time']);   
    if ($ad == $bd) {
        return 0;
    }
return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
}
if ($data !== NULL) {
    usort($data, "cmp");
    for($i=(count($data)-1)-($feed-1);$i>=(count($data)-10)-($feed-1);$i--){
        if($data[$i]['type']=='image'){ echo $data[$i]['name']; }
    }
}
```

I am JUST learning functions and have VERY limited experience with arrays, mostly with mysql arrays so I have no idea how to write this in such a way it returns the $data[] array properly as needed.

Comment: Where is $data originally defined? The first time I see it (outside the function at the top) is in the last code block. Based on what you have written, $data IS null in the last if statement

Comment: As I said I am still very new to functions and arrays. I thought I could output $results[] as an array to create the $data[] array. Perhaps I am doing the entire function wrong and that is why I can't echo results properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted the use of `$results` and `$data`

Here you use your `$results` array as input/output :

```
$tree = getDirEnties($directoryToScan, $results);
```

Then later you try to print `$data`

```
if ($data !== NULL) {
  usort($data, "cmp");
  for($i=(count($data)-1)-($feed-1);$i>=(count($data)-10)-($feed-1);$i--){
    if($data[$i]['type']=='image'){ echo $data[$i]['name']; }
  }
}
```

But the way you written the code, all your needs are in `$results`. Use `$results` !

```
if ($results !== NULL) {
  usort($results, "cmp");
  for($i=(count($results)-1)-($feed-1);$i>=(count($results)-10)-($feed-1);$i--){
    if($results[$i]['type']=='image'){ echo $results[$i]['name']; }
  }
}
```

Comment: considering I using a sort function to sort out dozens of data[] arrays by time, doing this using a data[] array is somewhat important. Is it really as easy as just switching out $data and $results? going to try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the entire array, use this. `print_r(array_values($ARR));`

Comment: want to try that again?

Comment: test it, then tell me that again

Comment: printr is not a php function

Comment: Sorry, its `print_r`

Comment: Why would you exclude the key? That is like 'the address' of the value...

Comment: better, not that i think this actually answers the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

The answer I marked correct, basically laid out my answer for me although it wasn't "exactly" what I wanted in terms of code. Ultimately all I had to do was change my variables and output a touch.

```
$tree = getDirEnties($directoryToScan, $results);
```

to

```
$tree = getDirEnties($directoryToScan, $data);
```

then

```
echo $tree; // I can't believe I missed this
```

then

```
return $results;
```

to

```
return $data;
```

Finally because I am sorting times with usort I had to change

```
'time' => filemtime($path)
```

to

```
'time' => date('F d Y h:i A', (filemtime($path)))
```